# Show that there does not exist any non-zero homomorphism f : S3 → Z3.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I am not the best at group theory, a lot of concepts are still a little fuzzy for me so I'd really appreciate explanations that are in detail.

Currently trying to prove this using the first isomorphism theorem, I know that the kernel has to be non-trivial because f cannot be one to one.

Comment: might be helpful to just write a multiplication table for the first group, whatever symbols you are using... a homomorphism from non-commutative to commutative will tend to force lots of elements to map to the identity, because  $\varphi(ab) = \varphi(a) \varphi(b) = \varphi(b) \varphi(a) = \varphi(ba)$

Comment: It's about homomorphism

Comment: also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/572250/264

Comment: Can someone explain how to find the order of a transposition?

Comment: and thank you very much Zev Chonoles!